# How can I compare two lists in python, and return that the second need to have the same values regardless of order?

Tags: python, list, comparison

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 4, 3, 1]
c = [2, 3]
```

When comparing a to b, should return `True`: all items in `a` are presented in `b`, and all items in `b` are presented in `a`.

When comparing `a` to `c`, should return `False`: there are items in `a` that don't exist on `c`.

What is the *pythonic* way to do it?

Comment: Are there duplicate entries in your lists?

Comment: There are no duplicates.

Comment: If order doesn't matter, you should use sets instead of lists.

Comment: Also, dig the name @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS

Comment: Why should I use sets in the domain I provided? `sorted(a) == sorted(b)` seems to me to be more simple and more readable. The compared lists aren't going to be huge - each one will have at most 10 items, and this comparison is going to be made only a few times. Although @marr75's says that using set is more readable (I know there are another arguments on his answer), I think @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams'a solution is more simple and easier to use in my context.

Comment: Sets won't work if there are duplicates or if the items are unhashable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sort, then compare.

```
sorted(a) == sorted(b)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use sets or frozensets.

```
set_a = {1, 2, 3, 4} #python 2.7 or higher set literal, use the set(iter) syntax for older versions
set_b = {2, 4, 4, 1}

set_a == set_b

set_a - set_b == set_b - set_a
```

The biggest advantage of using sets over any list method is that it's highly readable, you haven't mutated your original iterable, it can perform well even in cases where a is huge and b is tiny (checking whether a and b have the same length first is a good optimization if you expect this case often, though), and using the right data structure for the job is pythonic.

Comment: The possible downside is that you're not allowed to have duplicates in a set.

Answer (score 3):

Turn them into sets:

```
>>> set([1,2,3,4]) == set([2,4,3,1])
True

>>> set([2, 3]) == set([1,2,3,4])
False
```

If your lists contain duplicate items, you'll have to compare their lengths too. Sets collapse duplicates.

Comment: Checking length is not enough: `[1,1,2,3] != [1,2,3,3]`

Comment: @Howard: But the only criteria were: all items in `a` are presented in `b`, and all items in `b` are presented in `a`. By those criteria, `[1,1,2,3] == [1,2,3,3]`.

Comment: By strictest description of his problem, length isn't necessary, the questioner described a test where all items in a appear in b.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Yes, you're right. I interpreted the question a bit differently.